# I cannot set content_security_policy for my google earth packaged app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, google-earth, google-chrome-app

I am trying to create a packaged app that uses google earth API.  However, while running the app, I get an error that says:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://www.google.com/jsapi' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

So I added a line in the manifest that says

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com/jsapi; object-src 'self'",
```

However, now chrome complains and displays the following error:

```
There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
'content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, and this is a packaged app.
```

Comment: Packaged apps can't set a more permissive CSP than the default. You can create a sandboxed iframe with certain CSP limitations relaxed, though.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the API from a [sandbox](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/sandboxingEval.html), or more likely in a [webview](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/webview_tag.html).